# Sending to another channel inside select creates deadlock

Tags: go, deadlock

Sending to another channel inside select creates deadlock. I'm trying to understand why this happens. Is it because the select statement holds the lock of all the channels that it is listening to at the same time?

This is the code snippet that I've used to test it:

```golang
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
)

func main() {
        c1:= make(chan int)
        c2:= make(chan int)

        go func() {
                time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
                c2 <- 1
        }()

        for {
                select {
                case i := <-c1:
                        fmt.Println(i)
                case i := <-c2:
                        c1 <- i
                }
        }
}
```

And this is the output:

```sh
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.main()
        /home/user/test/main.go:22 +0x15e
```

Answer (score 2):

A channel created with `make(chan int)` is **unbuffered**. Sending and receiving block until the other side is ready.

In your example, your main goroutine is blocked on `c1 <- i` waiting for someone to receive from `c1`. But the only place for that to happen is three lines above in the same goroutine.

I recommend you go through the [channels](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2) section of the tour again, it covers buffered and unbuffered channels.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a buffered channel for c1. Because when you send to c1 i.e.,

```
case i := <-c2:
    c1 <- i
}
```

So it c1 is blocked until there's no receiver for it. So it's blocked there and hence a deadlock. If you make it a buffered channel, then it'll be a non-blocking send so that in the next iteration i.e.,

```
case i := <-c1:
```

this case gets selected and the value is printed. Now you need to exit or continue sending either to `c1` or `c2` so that select doesn't keep on blocking because if you do not return or do not send any value to c1 or c2, then again deadlock will happen. I have used a return, though.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // Buffered c1
    c1 := make(chan int, 1)
    // Unbuffered c2
    c2 := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
        // Send to c2 which will be captured in select block
        c2 <- 1
    }()

    for {
        select {
        case i := <-c1:
            // Print i
            fmt.Println(i)
            // Exit
            return
        case i := <-c2:
            // Send to buffered channel c1 so that c1
            // can receive it next iteration (for)
            c1 <- i
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code when you initialize the channel

```
c1:= make(chan int)
```

you are creating a unbuffered channel and the subsequent code in your selectcase will be blocked will it reaches

```
c1 <- i
```

You can read more about it on https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2

> By default, sends and receives block until the other side is ready. This allows goroutines to synchronize without explicit locks or condition variables

You can turn the channel into a buffered channel with at least length 1 so that sending to the channel c1 is not blocking

```
c1 := make(chan int, 1)
```

or you can create another goroutine to send the value. That way, the new goroutine will be blocked and the for loop will be able to retrieve the value from c1.

```
for {
    select {
    case i := <-c1:
        fmt.Println(i)
    case i := <-c2:
        go func() {
            c1 <- i
        }()
    }
}
```